# Join two tables on data not found in another

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am modelling a movie theater ticket booking system and wondering how to display seats that have not been booked for a particular screening of a movie

How can I join these tables to show the seats that have not been booked for a specified screening?

I have the following tables

## SEAT

- Seat_ID
- Row
- Number
- Auditorium_ID (FK)

## SEAT_RESERVED

- ID (PK)
- Seat_ID (FK)
- Screening_ID (FK)

## SCREENING

- Screening_ID (PK)
- Movie_ID (FK)
- Auditorium_ID (FK)

## AUDITORIUM

- Auditorium_ID (PK)
- Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this result by `LEFT JOIN`ing the list of seats in the auditorium for a given screening to the list of reserved seats; seats are not reserved will not match and have an `Seat_Reserved.ID` of `NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Screening C
JOIN Seat S ON S.Auditorium_ID = C.Auditorium_ID
LEFT JOIN Seat_Reserved R ON R.Screening_ID = C.Screening_ID AND R.Seat_ID = S.Seat_ID
WHERE C.Screening_ID = ?
  AND R.ID IS NULL
```

You can also use a `NOT EXISTS` clause to achieve the same result:

```
SELECT *
FROM Screening C
JOIN Seat S ON S.Auditorium_ID = C.Auditorium_ID
WHERE C.Screening_ID = ?
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM Seat_Reserved R
                  WHERE R.Screening_ID = C.Screening_ID
                    AND R.Seat_ID = S.Seat_ID)
```

The `?` in the queries is a placeholder for the screening that you are interested in.